# How to dynamically add scripts received from CMS to <Head>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have an endpoint which returns an array of scripts. These scripts can either be with a `src` i.e. `<script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"><script>` attribute OR they may also have body content i.e. something like; `<script>(function(// do something to generate scripts))<script>` which will create new scripts on the fly.

I'm currently using `getServerSideProps` to get the data from each individual page and then in `_app.js` I am getting that data from `pageProps`. The data is landing in fine, however I was hoping to simply return the script code in `<Head>` but obviously React escapes any HTML that isn't set using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` so that makes this task somewhat more difficult.

I have looked through the documentation and see no feasible way to just simply put the script in string form in the `<Head>` tag. This would be the simplest solution.

Here's my idea;

1. I would check if the script has a src, if it doesn't we can assume that it has body content and thus will create new scripts on the fly.
2. If the script has an src, we extract it and return a JSX script tag and populate the src with what we got back from the CMS.
3. If the script has no src tag, we remove all script tags and then use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to set the contents of the script to a JSX script instance.

Is there an another way to do this, with fewer steps? It feels like there should be.

Comment: FYI; it's always best just to ask how to do something, rather than for the best way to do something. No one's going to answer a "how to" question with the worst way to do something :). As far as this question goes, it would probably be helpful to know more details about the CMS; who knows? Maybe someone has used it before.

Comment: Hey, good point regarding the 'best' question! The CMS doesn't matter, since the data lands however it lands i.e. in string format. We can just assume that I have a string that is either of the two cases mentioned above, because at the end of the day that's all that matters. Hope this helps clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`html-to-react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react). Here is an example:

```js
import Head from "next/head";
import { Parser } from "html-to-react";

const IndexPage = () => {
  const { parse } = new Parser();
  const scriptString = "<script>console.log('hello')</script>";
  return (
    <>
      <Head>{parse(scriptString)}</Head>
      <div>Hello World.</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default IndexPage;
```

Comment: are there any others way?

Comment: Hi @brc-dd, Are there any other ways without install a library?

Comment: @huykon225 You can do what the OP was doing. It doesn't require any extra library.

Comment: Can you share me detail or any guide?